# Why is a powershell script restarting automatically

Tags: powershell

I'm using a Powershell script to run another sql script. My issue is that this script is running at some point but then it stops and restart from the beginning.

Do you have any idea why is it doing this? 
Here's the Ps1 script I'm talking about:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "$script.sql" `
               -Database $database `
               -Server $server `
               -UserName $username `
               -Password $password `
               -QueryTimeout 65534 `
               -Verbose | Out-Null) 4> "$script.log"
```

is it related somehow to the Timeout I've set?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which timeout? Are you invoking the script in a scheduled task?

Comment: At first you should check out the SQL Server error log.

Comment: Actually, I'm invoking it manually.

Comment: And when I check the SQL Server log, it's not saying there's an error or something it's just restart from the beginning, that's what I'm finding odd :(

Comment: Any chance you are calling the same `$script.sql` a second time?

Comment: How do you know it restart ? If you open ISE and run it, does it work ? Also, there are error in your script, such as the parenthesis alone after Out-Null. Also, unless I am mistaken "4>" is invalid syntax in powershell.

Comment: I know from the logs that it's restarting from the beginning because I'm computing some indicators for a range of date so I can track which date is done.

Comment: I will check if I'm calling the same $script.sql twice (it might be a reason), but as far as I'm concerned, it's only invoked once

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue.  I doubt the timeout is the issue.  I think to help further I'd need to see the SQL script you are running.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Did you get any solution?